# Add Custom Functions to a Class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

all i want to do is add a custom method to my controller so that i can reuse them in other methods inside my controller. eg.:

```
class SampleController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        generateCode();
        sendEmail();
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Custom Functions
     */
    function sendEmail()
    {

    }

    function generateCode()
    {

    }
}
```

Here i just want to be able to call `sendEmail()` and `generateCode()` in my index method but i keep getting function not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not global functions so you can't use them like that. They are class methods with scope. Note the changes I made for you:

```
<?php

class SampleController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->generateCode();
        $this->sendEmail();
    }

    // . . .

    /**
     * Custom Functions
     */
    private function sendEmail()
    {

    }

    private function generateCode()
    {

    }
}
```

You really should do some OOP PHP tutorials, or read some books, or take a course. This is very basic stuff that you should not need to be asking on stack overflow.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Sorry and thanks, i forgot, switching between languages is a real pain. :D